# rmarkdown: kable, xtable or tab_df tables in Word doc

Tags: r, ms-word, r-markdown, kable

````
---
output:
  word_document: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
data("mtcars")
library(tidyverse)
library(xtable)
library(sjPlot)
library(kableExtra)
```

```{r, results='asis'}
df <- mtcars %>% 
group_by(cyl) %>% 
summarise(disp = mean(disp), 
        wt = mean(wt), 
        n = n()
)
kable(df)

# tab_df(df)
# xtable(df) 
```
````

I have tried `xtable`, `tab_df`, and `kable` to generate a word document with a table. When "knit to HTML document", all tables looked fine. When "knit to Word", xtable didn't show the table while `tab_df` and `kable` produced a table with only one column:

```
kable(df) 
cyl
disp
wt
n
4
105.1364
2.285727
```

Comment: `kable` works for me if I only load `tidyverse` and `knitr`. It seems `kableExtra` is likely the issue. See this: https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/308.

Comment: Yes, it also works. Thanks!

Comment: You can knit to HTML, and then copy/paste or directly open the HTML-file in Word, which should render the tables properly as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I experimented with [`flextable`](https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/articles/overview.html) quite a bit the last few days and it might be the best option when you have to work with Word:

````
---
output:
  word_document: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
data("mtcars")
library(tidyverse)
library(flextable)
```

```{r, results='asis'}
mtcars %>% 
group_by(cyl) %>% 
summarise(disp = mean(disp), 
        wt = mean(wt), 
        n = n()
) %>% 
  flextable() %>% 
  align(part = "all") %>% # left align
  set_caption(caption = "Table 1: Example") %>% 
  font(fontname = "Calibri (Body)", part = "all") %>% 
  fontsize(size = 10, part = "body") %>% 
  # add footer if you want
  # add_footer_row(values = "* p < 0.05. ** p < 0.01. *** p < 0.001.", 
  #                colwidths = 4) %>% 
  theme_booktabs() %>% # default theme
  autofit()

```
````

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is exactly what I need!